# Can someone explain to me how this statement is an exclude?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone tell me how this is an exclude?

Assuming that tableID is auto generated and in columnY there can be value of 0 or 1. This statement should exclude everything were columnY has a value of 1.

```
SELECT *
     FROM [table].[dbo].[one] AS t1
LEFT JOIN [table].[dbo].[one] AS t2
     ON (t1.ColumnX = t2.ColumnX AND columnY = 1)
WHERE t1.tableID IS NULL
```

So the table would look something like this:

```
ID   |   ColumnX   | ColumnY
1        Blue        0
2        Blue        1
3        Red         0 
4        Red         0
5        Red         1
```

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed the query correctly? A `WHERE righttable.column is null` is a common way to locate rows from `lefttable` which have no matching rows produced by a `lefttable LEFT JOIN righttable`. But you're showing `WHERE lefttable.column is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain... a query that's very close to yours. Let me alter it to:

```
SELECT *
    FROM [table].[dbo].[one] AS t1
    LEFT JOIN [table].[dbo].[one] AS t2
         ON (t1.ColumnX = t2.ColumnX AND t2.columnY = 1)
    WHERE t2.tableID IS NULL
```

This query retrieves all rows from `t1`, then checks to see if there exists a row in `t2` (i.e. the same table) with the same value of `ColumnX`, where `ColumnY` is 1.

If that row *doesn't* exist, then it'll list all rows from `t1` (plus a bunch of nulls from `t2`) with this value of `ColumnX`. However, if that row *does* exist, then the rows with that value of `ColumnX` will be excluded (because `t2.id IS NOT NULL`).

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f40ad/1)'s a SQLFiddle to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT *
     FROM [table].[dbo].[one] AS t1
LEFT JOIN [table].[dbo].[one] AS t2
     ON (t1.ColumnX = t2.ColumnX) AND (columnY = 1)
     WHERE t1.tableID IS NULL
```

So the table would look something like this:

```
ID   |   ColumnX   | ColumnY
2        Blue        1
5        Red         1
```

Or you can use this

```
SELECT *
     FROM [table].[dbo].[one] AS t1
LEFT JOIN [table].[dbo].[one] AS t2
     ON (t1.ColumnX = t2.ColumnX) 
     WHERE t2.columnY = 1 AND t1.tableID IS NULL
```

So the table would look something like this:

```
ID   |   ColumnX   | ColumnY
2        Blue        1
5        Red         1
```

I hope this will help you. thanks